# Rewrite a single URL using ModRewrite, with domain pointers

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My `.htaccess` is at root level, and serves a number of hosted domains (I'm using domain pointers).

I want to redirect a single URL on one of those domains:

`http://www.pointerdomain.com/first.html` to `http://www.pointerdomain.com/single.html`

But I can't see any documentation on how to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems vague, but would this work for you?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.pointerdomain\.com
RewriteRule ^first.html$ /single.html
```